# Jump on specific line in txt file

Tags: python, linux

I have a big text file and I want to open it and jump on a line that contains a specific string.
What I managed to do is jump on a specific line number.

```
import os
os.system('sudo gedit +50 test.txt')
```

How can i edit the code so that it searches for a specific string instead of a line number?

Comment: Use `grep -n` to get the line number and then use the current approach. What I don't understand is why you use Python for this.

Comment: Running `gedit` with `sudo` is ill-advised at best. What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: i want to preview a text file to the user, but instead from presenting the file from the start i want to jump at a line that will contain a specific string

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the line as first ocurrence of text that are you looking for with next line:

```
   gedit +$(grep -n "id" test.txt  | head -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d ':')  test.txt
```

This `grep -n "text_to_find" test.txt  | head -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d ':'` means:

1. `grep ...` Tell me all lines where there are  "test_to_find" and prefix with line number
2. `head ...`: get first occurrence
3. `cut ...` get the line number

You have to fix it in case that there are not ocurrences

Answer (score 0):

You're not really going to be able to open the file and jump straight to a line, without first doing some logic to figure where that line is.

This should do the trick:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        if 'My Search String Here' in line:
            print line
```

You may also want to look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But i want the file to be displayed in gedit not in shell, so i was wandering if there is a command in Linux to open the file and do like a ctrl+f search to jump on the line.